# Overwriting character in dynamically allocated array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to overwrite character in 2D array.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i,j;

    char** arr=malloc(sizeof(char*)*4);
    for ( i = 0; i<4;i++){      
            arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);            
        }
    for ( i = 0; i<4; i++){
        for ( j = 0; j<4; j++){         
            if((i==0&&j==0)||(i==0&&j==3)||(i==3&&j==0)||(i==3&&j==3)){         
                arr[i][j] = '=';    
                }
            else{
                arr[i][j] = ' ';
                }                               
            printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
            }   

        printf("\n");
        }       
    arr[1][1]= '+';
    printf("%c", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

2D array with space-bar is printed firstly and i am trying to overwrite '+' in the arr

therefore, firstly, the code will return 2D array.

Assume that 0 is space-bar since i cannot upload image yet in stackoverflow ;(

```
=00=

0000

0000

=00=
```

After then i want to add `+` in the `arr[1][1]`, so 2D array will be printed as

```
=00=

0+00

0000

=00=
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @juanchopanza Sir, I guess either the code is crashing, or printing garbage, as UB. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry, but I wasn't asking you!

Comment: @juanchopanza I did not intend to interrupt, in that case. Just trying to guess....anyway, sorry.

Comment: @CbeginnerXO - Another question is why you decided to allocate 16 characters dynamically? Much simpler would be `char arr[4][4];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the printing part,

```
 printf("%c", arr);
```

You cannot print the *whole* `arr` using `%c`. You need a loop to do that, element by element.

You can re-use the same loop conditions which you've used for initialization of the elements at the very beginning to print out the modified array.

FWIW, `arr` is not the correct type expcted by `%c` and this invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: There should be a badge for "Mismatched format specifiers sniping".